# A static animation system

Tags: java, animation

I am trying to make an static animation system, for my game, just a basic system that switches pictures after an amount of miliseconds. I want my character to do some basic walking, and some basic animations based by an amount of pictures. Like, it plays all the images in a row, in a certain speed, so it does an animation, how would I go by making this in Java? Would be nice if someone explained how I do this, because I need it.

Comment: *I am trying to make an static animation system...*  -- What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried following the examples of bucky, on youtube. http://www.thenewboston.com/?cat=35&pOpen=tutorial , tuts 8 - 13, but, I am not using fullscreen, and i'm using a different way of drawing the screen, i'm using swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read through the [How to Use Swing Timers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) tutorial.  Animation is not *that* complicated to get something simple working - multiple times a second you change the position of an image, or switch one image for another, or somehow manipulate the displayed image.

It sounds like you're trying to incorporate this into a game environment, but your question doesn't make sense to me - are you dealing with sprites?  If so you should read this tutorial on [Sprite Animation in Java.](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/893471/Fun-with-Java-Sprite-Animation-Part-1.htm)

Comment: Well, it's just a player image, and I want him to do simple animations like walk.

Comment: OK, then you definitely want to read up on sprites.  There are a whole bunch of Java libraries that handle these for you, but if you want the learning experience, read up on what sprites are, make a class structure to support them, then go to town.